# Did anybody do any research on average size of iPhone Game at App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, size

I am wondering if anybody did some research of average size of iPhone games in app store, just to know what should be the best size of iPhone game when developing. like 10, 20, 30, 40, etc in MBs?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The best size is whatever size makes sense for your game.

Answer (score 0):

The current iTunes download-size limit via cellular network is 50mb. Anything above has to be downloaded via Wifi. Keep in mind that there actually are potential customers without WiFi networks.